# Can Hadoop run on Nginx?

Tags: nginx, hadoop

Is that possible to run Hadoop on Nginx? 
if so, is there any reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nginx is a http server, it has nothing to do with Hadoop.

Answer (score 1):

Well... Maybe you meant map/reduce jobs reading/writing over http?

The answer would be no... It would be too inefficient, because hadoop map reduce requires that data is processed locally.

Even when implementing streaming hadoop map/reduce jobs  , data is read/written locally by a non java program.